# How to get a list of all pipelines run for gitlab scheduled pipeline

Tags: gitlab

I have a scheduled pipeline setup in gitlab, but when I query it, it only shows the last run pipeline. I would like to be able to get a list of all of the pipelines it has run so I can perform some analysis on them. I tried looking into both the rest and graphql apis and I didn't seem to find anything that would solve this. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can actually list all pipelines triggered by schedule using GitLab REST API

```
GET /projects/:id/pipeline_schedules/:pipeline_schedule_id/pipelines
```

Your request attributes must contain the project `id` and the `pipeline_schedule_id` as both are required. You could replace the project `id` with the URL-encoded path of your owned projects.

#### Example Request:

```
curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <your_access_token>" "https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/29/pipeline_schedules/13/pipelines"
```

#### Example Response:

```
[
  {
    "id": 47,
    "iid": 12,
    "project_id": 29,
    "status": "pending",
    "source": "scheduled",
    "ref": "new-pipeline",
    "sha": "a91957a858320c0e17f3a0eca7cfacbff50ea29a",
    "web_url": "https://example.com/foo/bar/pipelines/47",
    "created_at": "2016-08-11T11:28:34.085Z",
    "updated_at": "2016-08-11T11:32:35.169Z"
  },
  {
    "id": 48,
    "iid": 13,
    "project_id": 29,
    "status": "pending",
    "source": "scheduled",
    "ref": "new-pipeline",
    "sha": "eb94b618fb5865b26e80fdd8ae531b7a63ad851a",
    "web_url": "https://example.com/foo/bar/pipelines/48",
    "created_at": "2016-08-12T10:06:04.561Z",
    "updated_at": "2016-08-12T10:09:56.223Z"
  }
]
```

Reference link https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/pipeline_schedules.html#get-all-pipelines-triggered-by-a-pipeline-schedule

Comment: Ah, looks like this was introduced in v15.3. I'm guessing we are not running that version as it is not yet released. Do you know of a way to do this for previous releases?

Comment: Yes, v15.3 is yet to be released. What you can do now is to list pipelines per project using `GET /projects/:id/pipelines` which is available since 14.1 but the schedule pipelines is a requested feature that is newly developed. GitLab releases a version every month on the 22nd, so this is expected to be released on the 22nd of August 2022 https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/368566 https://about.gitlab.com/upcoming-releases/

Comment: Thanks! Apparently I’m not the only one requesting this feature.

Comment: Calling `GET /projects/:id/pipelines` works for me. Great ... well nearly. It returns just 15 entries from `"created_at": "2022-09-01T14:25:03.152Z"`. Final result is dated `2022-09-16T08:12:28.983Z` (even though the pipeline ran successfully today. Is this just a limitation of the feature?